# How to check if a number in a list is greater than the number before it - python

Tags: python

I have 3 sets of data zipped together (date,somenumber,price). I want to iterated through the table and whenever somenumber is less than somenumber before it in the list I want to pull the date,somenumber,price for when that happens. Currently I just have:

```
for a,b,c in zip(date,somenumber,price):
    print(a,b,c)
```

## and it prints something like:

```
2018-01-30 18:42:00 859235 6.95
2018-02-01 09:08:00 323405 7.43
2018-02-02 15:16:00 528963 6.4
2018-02-05 18:48:00 808739 7.91
2018-02-07 14:42:00 462541 7.33
2018-02-10 18:48:00 598001 6.21
2018-02-11 03:32:00 650558 7.31
2018-02-11 11:28:00 670392 6.21
```

When somenumber went from 808739 to 462541 I want to return the data for that lower number:
2018-02-07 14:42:00 462541 7.33

Thanks!

Comment: 323405 is less than 859235. Do you want to report it, too? If not, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will compare somenumber+1 to somenumber, and if somenumber + 1 (the next number in the sequence is less than the current) it will print all data for that row. If it is not less it will not print anything.

```
for a,b,c,d in zip(date, somenumber, somenumber[1:], price):
    if c < b:
        print(a, b, c, d)
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from the question is every time, the value of `somenumber` decreases in the next row, it should print the row. It's very easy to implement. Just store the previous value in another variable (`prev_number`). For the first row, though, we need to initialize `prev_number` to the minimum number possible. Following is the solution:

```
import sys
prev_number = -sys.maxint - 1    #initialize prev_number to lowest possible number in python
for a,b,c in zip(date,somenumber,price):
    if b < prev_number:
        print(a,b,c)
    prev_number = d
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: there is no lowest possible integer number in python:  `n = -sys.maxint**10` is smaller then what you used. It is also not needed: `prev_number = min(somenumber)-1` would be enough and you can get rid of the import

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's right. but here, we don't know the min range (some number) right. That's why we can use sys.maxint values.